# Hibernate session factory one new session for multiple DAO

Tags: hibernate, sessionfactory

I got multiple DAO class which extends to a BaseDAO, and I open a new Session in the BaseDAO so that all the DAO will be using the same session.

```
@Autowired
public BaseDAOImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    super(sessionFactory);
    this.mySession = sessionFactory.openSession();
    logger.info("My Session is Open." );
}

public Session getMySession(){
    return this.mySession;
}   

@Repository("countryDAO")
public class CountryDAOImpl extends BaseDAOImpl<Country> implements CountryDAO{

    @Autowired
    public CountryDAOImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        super(sessionFactory);
    } 
}

@Repository("regionDAO")
public class RegionDAOImpl extends BaseDAOImpl<Region> implements RegionDAO{

    @Autowired
    public RegionDAOImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        super(sessionFactory);
    } 
}
```

In my service class I auto-wiring 2 DAO.

```
@Autowired
CountryDAO countryDAO;

@Autowired
RegionDAO regionDAO;
```

In my console I saw My Session is Open printed twice. Does it mean it open 2 new session? I don't want to use current session for some reason, so I use openSession(). When I do countryDAO.getMySession().clear() it only clear the entity loaded in countryDAO session but not regionDAO.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it makes 2 different sessions.
You can verify it by adding the log

```
logger.info("My Session is Open:" + this.mySession.toString());
```

If you want to use 1 session for all your DAOS, use
`.getCurrentSession()` instead of `.openSession()`. Also for this to work, you need to update your hibernate config with

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

Comment: How can I only used 1 session for all the DAO?

Comment: My program got a looping and I need to commit each loop so I don't want to use getCurrentSession()

Comment: I'm not clear about your need. You should add your looping and "commit each loop" to your question.